# Magento Ajax Login, return new form key from controller?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, magento, authentication

I have a custom ajax login module. I added the form key hidden field and I send that off through ajax. I am able to login successfully.

The problem is that I have multiple forms in that page. When I try to use the other forms after login (ajax), it seems that Magento changes the form key upon login because after login they don't work. If you refresh the page while staying logged in they work.

The question is. Do I return the new form key from the controller upon successful login? Is that any sort of security risk?

I supposed returning the new form key will allow me to set the hidden form key fields so that the other forms on the page will work...

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the form keys after each request using JS. This is not a security risk because it's essentially the same thing that happens if the page was refreshed. After a refresh, the form keys are updated, so you need to mimic this with your AJAX callback.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's what I figured. But security is hard and I wanted to make sure there are no obvious pitfalls.